# Calculate percentage between inputs then change background colouraccourding to result percentage using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How do I multiply input="rate" with input="days" and show result in input="client-price". Then calculate the percentage from input="client-price" with input="my-price" and show the result in input="margin". After that change colour of "e" so if Margin percentage is above 50% its div colour background changes to red and if it's below 50% changes to green?

Here is my form:

```js
  $(".calc input").keyup(function() {
        var rate = +$("#rate").val();
        var days = +$("#days").val();
        var client_price = rate * days;
        client_price = Math.ceil(client_price);
        $("#client-price").val(client_price);
    });
   $(".calc-two input").keyup(function() {
        var client_price = +$("client-price").val();
        var my_price = +$("#my-price").val();
        var margin = (my_price * 100) / client_price;
        margin = Math.ceil(margin);
        $("#margin").val(margin);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a calc"><label>Rate</label><input id="rate" name="rate" type="text"></div>
<div class="b calc"><label>Days</label><input id="day" name="day" type="text" ></div>
<div class="c calc-two">
<label>Client Price</label>
<input id="client-price" name="client-price" type="text">
</div>
<div class="d calc-two">
<label>My price</label>
<input id="my-price" name="my-price" type="text">
</div>
<div class="e"><label>Margin</label><input id="margin" name="margin" type="text" value=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add some part and edit the error, I'll let you do the part of the final percentage

```js
$(".calc input").keyup(function() {
        var rate = +$("#rate").val();
        var days = +$("#days").val();
        var client_price = rate * days;
        client_price = Math.ceil(client_price);
       
        $("#client-price").val(client_price);
    });
   $(".calc-two input").keyup(function() {
        var client_price = +$("#client-price").val();
        var my_price = +$("#my-price").val();
        var margin = (my_price * 100) / client_price;
        margin = Math.ceil(margin);
      
        if(margin > 50){$('.e').css("background-color","red");}else{$('.e').css("background-color","green");}
        $("#margin").val(margin);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a calc"><label>Rate</label><input id="rate" name="rate" type="text"></div>
<div class="b calc"><label>Days</label><input id="days" name="day" type="text" ></div>
<div class="c calc-two">
<label>Client Price</label>
<input id="client-price" name="client-price" type="text">
</div>
<div class="d calc-two">
<label>My price</label>
<input id="my-price" name="my-price" type="text">
</div>
<div class="e"><label>Margin</label><input id="margin" name="margin" type="text" value=""></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that! I'm new to JavaScript so this worked like a charm for me. Such an easy solution!

Comment: @epicdigital acept answer please.